# Remote Method doesn't have example in the explorer (Swagger) as the login has

Tags: loopbackjs

As per my understanding the User/login is a built-in remote method. On the explorer (swagger) its looks with all the needed details:

[image]

but on mine remote method, i don't have all the nice information such example and more:

[image]

How can i add Example Value also for my method which accept **Object**

Here is my json:

```
 "methods": {
"specifyGurdianPhone": {
  "accepts": [
    {
      "arg": "guardianPhone",
      "type": "Object",
      "required": true,
      "description": "{guardianPhone: \"+97255111111\"}",
      "http": {
        "source": "body"
      }
    }
  ],
  "returns": [
    {
      "arg": "success",
      "type": "Object",
      "root": true
    }
  ],
  "description": "",
  "http": {
    "verb": "post"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your param and response has "object" type. Swagger doesn't know how it looks like. To have such view you need specify model names as the type or describe possible properties one by one.

Example1:

```
{
   "specifyGurdianPhone": {
   "accepts": [
     {
       "arg": "guardianPhone",
       "type": "string", // !!! Now, swagger know the exact type of "guardianPhone" property
       "required": true
       "http": {
         "source": "form" // !!! Having the "form" here we say that it a property inside an object 
                          //     (it allows us to have the "string" type of the "object")
       }
     }
   ],
   "returns": [
     {
       "arg": "success",
       "type": "GuardianPhone", // !!! For example, let's return the full "GuardianPhone" instance
       "root": true
     }
   ],
   "description": "",
   "http": {
     "verb": "post"
   }
}
```

Example2:

```
 {
   "specifyGurdianPhone": {
   "accepts": [
     {
       "arg": "guardianPhone",
       "type": "object", 
       "model": "GuardianPhone" // !!! Another way to let swagger know the type of the body
                                    //     (the same will be true, if you make the type "GuardianPhone" instead of "object" and delete "model" property)
       "required": true
       "http": {
         "source": "body"
       }
     }
   ],
   "returns": [
     {
       ...
   ]
 }
```

Example3:

```
 {
   "specifyGurdianPhone": {
   "accepts": [
     {
       "arg": "guardianPhone",
       "type": "object", 
       "model": "GuardianPhone" // !!! Another way to let swagger know the type of the body
                                    //     (the same will be true, if you make the type "GuardianPhone" instead of "object" and delete "model" property)
       "required": true
       "http": {
         "source": "body"
       }
     }
   ],
   "returns": [
     {
       "arg": "success",

       // !!! Instead of a model name you can describe properties one by one, 
       //     but this trick will not work with arrays (it's true for "accepts" also)
       // !!! WARNING You need strong-remoting v3.15.0 or higher due to https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3717 for this approach
       "type": { 
         "id": {"type": "string", "description": "An id property"},
         "guardianPhone": {"type": "string"}
       },

       "root": true
     }
   ],
   "description": "",
   "http": {
     "verb": "post"
   }
 }
```

Comment: I just checked that and your solution not allow me to provide JSON as part of the body....   How the User/Login build-in method configured? this is what i am looking for...  in one hand to be able to provide JSON as part of the body and in other hand to have the details in swagger like the User/Login (POST)

Thanks for your time

Comment: @Omtechguy I described mechanic based on the response. The same true for accepts (I added another example to show it). There are many ways to do such description. I just don't know what from them mostly fit your needs

Comment: I need to pass JSON object as part of the body and i want to describe the properties on the OpenAPI. Can you advice how can i do it?

Comment: Check my examples, you need to create a loopback model (if you don't have it) and make accepts/response type === this loopback model (example 1 or example 2)

Comment: If you don't want to create another model, use the scenario from example 3. You can describe a type for accept/response as an object. The problem, this approach doesn't work for arrays types

Comment: Option 3 is not working... i am getting 500 AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: type must be either an array or a string. when i am specifying the type as:
"accepts": [
        {
          "arg": "args",
          "type":  {
            "id": {"type": "string" }
          },
          "required": true,
          "description": "",
          "http": {
            "source": "body"
          }
        }]


Could you please help?

Loopback version 3.22.2

Comment: For other developers - to avoid Treating unknown remoting type "xxx" as "any" use this fix:

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3514#issuecomment-467397852

Comment: Looks like, it because of this bug: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3717. You need strong-remoting v3.15.0 to fix it. Sorry, it worked for me without any updates because of my little loopback patches.